# Provisioning Device Owner and CosuApp

Tags: android, android-for-work, cosu

I setup a device owner application provisioning app as shown in google sample [NFC Provisioning](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NfcProvisioning) , with additional features to setup `EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION` and `EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM`. I would like as shown in the video of [Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/Za0OQo8DRM4?t=36m57s), to provide both device owner app and cosu app. 
How can I achieve this goal?

I should setup a single app which is both cosu and device owner or I have to provide download location automatically via nfc through provisioning app and instruct my device owner to download and install the specific app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both, it depends on your requirements. Google is using option 2.

option 1: Your device owner app can set itself as approved for [lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setLockTaskPackages(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[])). Then, on provisioning complete or boot complete, start your activity and call startLockTask().

option 2: After provisioning the device with you device owner app (device policy controller), you can download, silently install, whitelist for lock task mode, and then start the activity. I recommend passing cosu app download information to your DPC via NFC/QR code during provisioning using [EXTRA_PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034005/android-nfc-device-owner-provisioning-send-custom-properties-is-it-possible/44012305#44012305).

Additionally, I would check out this link for more information:
https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

You also have the option to use a third-party EMM or Google's relatively new [Android Management API](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#android-management-api).

Comment: Thanks very well explained! Cheers